# Swift 3: InputAccessoryView instantiated from .xib file

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uikeyboard, inputaccessoryview

I'm having a problem with instantiating my InputAccessoryView from a .xib file, where the inputAccessoryView doesn't react on input:

```
private var conversationToolBar = ConversationToolBar()

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return self.conversationToolBar
}
```

[image]

If I instantiate my inputAccessoryView from a method (createAccessoryView):

```
private var conversationToolBar = ConversationToolBar().createAccessoryView(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
```

My class:

```
class ConversationToolBar: UIView {

@IBOutlet var view: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.view = UINib(nibName: "ConversationToolBar", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    self.addSubview(self.view)
    self.view.frame = self.bounds
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.view = UINib(nibName: "ConversationToolBar", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    self.addSubview(self.view)
    self.view.frame = self.bounds
}

func createAccessoryView(width: CGFloat) -> UIView {
    let accessoryView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 100))
    accessoryView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let closeLabel = UITextField(frame: accessoryView.frame)
    closeLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    closeLabel.text = "Hello"
    closeLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    closeLabel.textAlignment = .center
    accessoryView.addSubview(closeLabel)

    return accessoryView
}
}
```

The behaviour works as expected.

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with showing `inputAccessoryView` as expected , and fixed it with calling this method to refresh input or accessory view :

```
closeLabel.reloadInputViews()
```

> Updates the custom input and accessory views when the object is the
>   first responder. You can use this method to refresh the custom input
>   view or input accessory view associated with the current object when
>   it is the first responder. The views are replaced immediately—that is,
>   without animating them into place. If the current object is not the
>   first responder, this method has no effect.